# java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: android, exception, onclick, illegalstateexception

I receive this error in crash report of just some users, but I don't understand it! The app works perfectly on almost all user devices!
**This is not a duplicate question, because app works always, but crashes some times!**

part of my code, shows the click is not something tricky:

```
fun grid_btn_clicked(v: View) {
        showData(findJson(K1)!!)
    }
```

and this is exception:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute
>   method for android:onClick
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
>          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
>          at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
>          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: can you add some piece of code where its crashing ?

Comment: Please put showData function body. Most probably there is a null in some cases as u use !!, maybe try wrapping it with let to get secured from crashes

Comment: If there was problem in showData why exception raised here?!

Comment: Dont really know because there is No code for other functions but if findJson can return null then u can get null in showData and in onClick

Comment: how have you set the click listener? If in the xml, then show the xml

Answer (score 0):

May b you are getting null value .Try putting your code under let and check while debugging that Are u gettingnull data from findJson(k1).

```
fun grid_btn_clicked(v: View) {
        findJson(k1).let{
           showData(it)
        }
    }
```